# SDL2 - render on texture alpha channels

Tags: sdl, alpha, sdl-2, alphablending

I'm looking for a way to render specifically on the alpha channels of a texture. the idea is to create a "mask" in runtime, i.e. to render a texture that will act as the alpha channels of another texture.

note: I know how to use alpha channels and color key so please don't explain about those :)  what I'm looking for is a way to generate a mask *dynamically in runtime*, using other textures.

I prefer a solution that takes an advantage of the graphic card, and not something involving getting the pixels buffer and manipulate them in the cpu.

is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

answering myself for others who might be interested:

1. the mask I use is a black and white texture: black is opaque, white is transparent. mask can be generated at runtime by rendering to texture.
2. when the mask texture is ready I copied it to another texture and inverted all the pixels. lets call this new texture "inverted mask".
3. before rendering the texture I wanted to mask, I render at the same position and size the inverted mask texture with additive blending. this will create a white silhouette at the shape of the mask I want to apply (since its additive the black pixels are transparent).
4. I then render the mask itself on the texture I want to mask, with additive blending. this will turn the background white (the pixels that are supposed to be transparent by the mask are now white. since its additive, the black pixels do no effect)
5. and finally I render the texture on screen with mod blending, exactly on the white silhouette I rendered at phase 3. the background white pixels will be transparent (because its mod) and what was the white silhouette will now be the texture, masked.

note: this is not ideal method, it involved with several renderings and manipulating texture pixels. but it was sufficient to my specific case and its pure SDL so good enough for me.

Comment: Are you inverting the mask using the CPU?  Because at that point, wouldn't it just be much faster to stream through the target texture once and simply set the alpha bytes to the values you want, then do a blend rendercopy?  I really hope in the future OpenSDL includes a basic shader, because it's so much more efficient to just do the composition yourself. :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if I get this wrong, but since you said "*on the alpha channel*" then it isn't possible, in terms of graphics, a channel is just a subgroup of AN image, along with the rgb channel, bw channel, sound channel(for depth,etc), etc.

But what I think you want to say is put ANOTHER image on top of the original mask, and the image on top is supposed to look like its covering the image below (then ajdust-adjust the transparency and viola), thus, giving off the image of a "mask".
EG:
A bride wearing a veil (the bride's face is the original image while the veil is translucent. By looking, you'd think of both as just one image.

There are two ways to do this, 1 being the easiest:

1. Edit the image that will act as a mask and change its opacity in an image manipulation program, remember to save it in png. After doing so, render the first image to texture then render the opacity edited image afterwards.
2. same as the first one but don't edit the second image, instead, just edit its alpha channel in SDL2. (With this method, you can control it dynamically along with time and rendering it to a texture takes advantage of the graphics card.)

Both would give of an image of 2 photos merged, with the second one acting as a mask.

Comment: nope you didn't understand me at all :)  I want to create something similar to stencil buffer but 2d and with SDL. and it needs to be in runtime so I can't use an image editing software to edit the alpha channels. thanks anyway though.

Comment: You should have mentioned stencil buffer in the description ahahhahaa, and since you mentioned mask* then I guess you're creating something complex like shadows?. Anyways, to limit the rendering then you could make another rect to signify the crop value of the texture, (let's say you're limiting it on a surface from below) you could have it's w and h be controlled by the edges of the surface below.